# Fourier transform for tempered distribution

Tags: fourier-transform, distribution-theory

> Let $S'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the set of all tempered distributions than the map
> $$
> F: S'(\mathbb{R}^n)\rightarrow S'(\mathbb{R}^n)\\
> FT(\varphi)\rightarrow T(\hat \varphi)\
> $$
> where $\hat \cdot$ denotes the fourier transform. Showthat $F$ is a continous, bijective operator.

It's clear that this holds for regular distributions, but how do I show this for distrubtions that are not regular ?

Would appreciate any help/hints

Comment: I can't figure out what it _means_ to say this holds for some subspace of $\mathcal S'$.

Comment: Do you about transposes of continuous linear maps?